# How to change type of class property based on value of env

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, dynamic-typing

I have a class

```
export class FeedItem extends Model {
  tags: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? string : string[]
}
```

I would like to set the type of tags as a string if I am running tests otherwise a string array. Currently it gives me an error. How do I achieve this in typescript?

Comment: There is no straightforward to do this. `process.env` is treated as a runtime value and the type of it will always be just `string`. `tsc` AFAIK does not access custom env variables during compilation time. Your best bet would probably to have two separate files in which you augment the `process.env` interface. During build for the test env, you include one and exclude the other. And the other way around for your non-test build. Then you could have a conditional type for `tags` like `tags: typeof process.env.NODE_ENV extends 'test' ? string : string[]`. ...

Comment: ... Your editor will not understand this logic though and will give you errors.

Comment: @TobiasS. if I set tags: string | string[] it seems to work but is there a more stricter way than this?

Comment: The real question here is, why is the type of `tags` different during testing?

Comment: @TobiasS. this is a sequelize model which runs on sqlite during tests and a postgres database in production. SQLite doesnt support array datatype in which you would normally store tags

Comment: Have you considered running an in memory Postgres instead? I found this one: https://github.com/oguimbal/pg-mem. Should be worth a try.

Comment: at a quick glance it doesnt seem to support sequelize. Also will it run as part of tests inside GitHub actions on CI because the current setup does

Comment: This is def not the way to do testing. You tests should be as close as possible to production. Changing the type from an array to a non array makes no sense as this invalidates your tests. You should probably look into mocking your database more than changing your types. All the code that touches FeedItem.tags will need to change also based on environment, which makes no sense.